# I am stuck in renaming image before uploading to server in android

Tags: java, android

I am try to get image from gallery and upload to server...  Before upload I need to change its name to a unique name... I am doing in this way but the name is not changing here. Kindly help me

```
chooseFiledestination= new File(getPath(selectedImage));
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),chooseFiledestination+"      This is Whole Path",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
String fileName = chooseFiledestination.getName();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),fileName+"      This is File name",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
File newFile = new File("mehdi.jpg");
chooseFiledestination.renameTo(newFile);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),chooseFiledestination+"    After Rename",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: You don't need to actually rename the file; you can send whatever name you like when you upload it, or the server can assign its own name.

Comment: Actually i am saving this pic in a folder there in server . in this case how can i retrieve latter if i don't know the name ..

Comment: i have to assign a unique name to it .. after successfully upload image i save the unique image name with user key in a table .. so i can display all the image of a user by userid